# Replace part of a string and upper case the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

everything good?
I would like some help from you, I have the following scenario:

```
STRING_ONE:
       string_two
   STRING_three     :
                   string_four:
    stringfive:
```

I need to identify words from the beginning of the line that end with :

after identifying the words, I need to erase the spaces and convert them to uppercase,
i tried doing some regex but as the words change I can't set the default for the replacement because i need to keep the same word, just removing the spaces and converting to capital letters

The result I'm trying to get is this:

```
STRING_ONE:
       string_two
   STRING_three     :
STRING_FOUR:
STRINGFIVE:
```

I can capture the words that match this pattern, with the following regex, but I don't know how to replace it by just erasing the spaces, keeping the rest of the string the same, and doing the upper case

```
^.*\b:
```

I tried to replace like this but it didn't work

```
"$1".toUpperCase()
```

Can anyone help please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not really replacing anything but instead you are looking for a pattern I used the pattern in a `String.prototype.match()` to identify the lines in which `.trim()` and `.toLowerCase()` need to be applied. The `.split("\n")` turns the initial string into an array over which I can then `.map()` the individual lines. At the end I `.join()` everything together again.

```js
const str=`STRING_ONE:
   string_two
   STRING_three     :
               string_four:
stringfive:`;

console.log(str
   .split("\n")
   .map(s=>s.match(/^\s*\w+:\s*$/) && s.trim().toUpperCase() || s )
   .join("\n")
);
```

Our regex patterns differ slightly:

- while yours (`/^.*\b:/`) will match any line that has at least one word-end followed by a colon in it
- mine (`/^\s*\w+:\s*$/`) is stricter and demands that there is *exactly* one word followed by a colon in a line that can optionally be padded by any number of whitespace characters on either side.

Comment: It worked perfectly my friend, thanks a lot for the help!
I still have a long way to learn :)